# Send UDP packet to a public IP using Boost.asio

Tags: c++, tcp, udp, boost-asio, p2p

I want to send UDP packets to my static IP `122.***.***.***` where an UDP server listens on port 1213.

```
udp::resolver resolver(io_serviceSend);
    udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(),"122.***.***.***","1213");
    udp::endpoint receiver_endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);

    udp::socket socket(io_serviceSend);
    socket.open(udp::v4());

    boost::shared_ptr<std::string> message(new std::string("Transfer"));

    socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(*message), receiver_endpoint);
```

but this fails. Is it because i am sending it to the private port rather than sending it to the NAT's port. but for TCP it works perfectly. 
Can some one explain me the theory or post a good link.

and my server code is

```
UDPTunnel::UDPTunnel(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
:socket_(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 1213))
{
start_receive();
}

void UDPTunnel::start_receive()
{
    socket_.async_receive_from(
            boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), remote_endpoint_,
            boost::bind(&UDPTunnel::handle_receive, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    cout << "\nUDP Started To Listening";
}

void UDPTunnel::handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,std::size_t)
{
 cout << "\nUDP Recieved Message";
 if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size)
  {
  cout << "\nRecieved Message";
  }
```

}

Comment: The code sample seems correct. Maybe the error is on the side of server.

Comment: Why do you mention NAT port ? Is there something you know about your setup that we don't ?

Comment: Since you mention NAT, is the UDP port open in the firewall, or is it forwarded correctly. Remember that TCP and UDP uses different ports, even if the numbers are the same.

Comment: I set up a client within the server and transmitted packets inside the server using its private ip 10.***.**.**. So it worked on the same port. If you'll guys saying i should enable the port in firewall then how come torrent app works?

Comment: The app you're talking about might be using UPNP or similar mechanisms to enable port forwarding. or add a firewall rule for itself.

Comment: @Mohammad Hi Mohammad, I have edited in my question the server code as well. I already added a new rule in firewall to enable port 1213. Does boost needed some extra functionality to be done to transmit UDP packets over a public network

Comment: Your are not checking the received message in server. how do you know it's not working?!

Comment: i am checking. There is a huge code in side "handle_receive" sorry i did not post it here but it's there.

Comment: @Mohammad i have edited and inserted a small portion in the server code

Comment: @Navin I dont see any problem in the code, if you are sure about your network setup, firewall and port forwarding (in case of NAT), then I don't have anything else to add.

Comment: @Navin No, boost does not need anything extra . You need to figure out which part of your infrastructure you need to fiddle with (e.g. open an outgoing firewall, enable _correct_ port forwarding on the gateway at the server side, and perhaps other things related to your setup.)

Comment: i bought the server from amazon. Ill look in to it and get back to you'll. The TCP connection work fine with the server the problem is only with the UDP connection.

Comment: @Mohammad and @ nos 
I installed wireshark and monitored the packets. The UDP packets are not even displaying in that, does this mean that there cannot be any firewall issue something wrong in the way i send the packet? as i said before there are no issue with TCP

Comment: @Mohammad  and nos Thanks guys. I need to open the UDP ports in the server console provided by amazon. Enabling it only in the windows firewall of the server is not enough. Now it's working. If you'll please post you answer as an answer so that i can vote you'll up.